# TikZ spy and Beamer uncover

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm trying to uncover a magnifying glass using the `\spy` functionality of TikZ, however, as you can see in the minimal working example below, the glass is there from frame 1. Does someone know how to fix this issue ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,spy,fixedpointarithmetic,patterns,arrows,decorations.text,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,positioning,shapes.symbols,chains}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    Space
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[spy scope={magnification=1.5, size=2cm},every spy in node/.style={remember picture,overlay,magnifying glass,circular drop shadow,fill=white,draw,ultra thick, cap=round}]
            \node[rectangle, draw, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] (N) {};
            \uncover<2->{\spy on (N) in node;}
            % \only<2>{\spy on (N) in node;}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `only` command you have commented out?

Comment: It's moving the text `Space` in the frame.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why `\uncover<2->` and `\visible<2->` do not work I don’t know, but here are two work-arounds:

### Work-Around 1: `\alt` + `\pgfkeysalso`

There are two `/.style`s and one `/.code`, to help with `beamer`:

- `invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0}`
  This style is not very `beamer` special because it sets only every opacity (draw, fill, text) to zero, which means: It is there, but you cannot see it. It occupies the same space, much like `\phantom`.
- `alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{\alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}}`
  This code handler uses two things:

  1. The `\alt<overlay>{arg1}{arg2}` macro provided by `beamer` that executes `arg1` when on `overlay`, otherwise `arg2`; and
  2. `\pgfkeysalso` which adds TikZ keys to a path without changing it otherwise. This is similar to adding `[some keys=values]` to a path.
- `visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}}`
  This style is rather a shortcut to `alt`. It does nothing to a path on `<#1>` but hides in otherwise.

If you want to use overlay specification with a `,`, e.g. `<2,4>`, you have to enclose it in `{ }`: `visible on={<2,4>}`. (For that same reason are the `alt` arguments enclosed in braces.)

#### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,spy,shapes.symbols}
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} 
    },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    Space
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[spy scope={magnification=1.5, size=2cm},every spy in node/.style={remember picture,overlay,magnifying glass,circular drop shadow,fill=white,draw,ultra thick, cap=round}]
            \node[rectangle, draw, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] (N) {};
            \spy[visible on=<2->] on (N) in node;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Work-Around 2: `overlay`

The TikZ key `overlay` prevents the update of the bounding box. The content is simply overlayed on the page with no respect for everything.

This does work in this case …

#### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,spy,shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Space
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[spy scope={magnification=1.5, size=2cm},every spy in node/.style={remember picture,overlay,magnifying glass,circular drop shadow,fill=white,draw,ultra thick, cap=round}]
      \node[rectangle, draw, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] (N) {};
      \only<2->{\spy[overlay] on (N) in node;}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I tried the `[overlay]` option but with `uncover`, not `only`, of course I had the same issue, should have tried that in the first place instead of bothering you. Anyway your code for `visible on` might help me for some other things, so thanks again !

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel May I ask why you used the key `remember picture` in the first example? When I run it, the key is preventing that anything is shown in the `spy-in` node. If I remove it, it works as required (TeX Live 2014)